# Convert to Date Time Format "2020-02-11T17:26:31-05:00"

Tags: java, datetime-format

Hi I am not able to understand what time format we need to use  in order to parse this date`2020-02-11T17:26:31-05:00`  I have tried using Date formatter and simple date format but its not working

Date is coming in this form ->**2020-02-11T17:26:31-05:00** I am not able to identify the type of this date

Below is snippet of code i have tried but its throwing exception

```
DateTimeFormatter responseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-SSSXXX'Z'",
                              Locale.ENGLISH);
                     responseDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(otmmResponseDate, responseFormatter);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/2131074

Comment: This is a ISO 8601 compliant instant format. You should check out other answers with this keyword. Look for java.time based solutions Java versions after 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a datetime `String` that contains an offset of minus five hours. You don't even have to use a `DateTimeFormatter` directly, because parsing this to an `OffsetDateTime` will do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateString = "2020-02-11T17:26:31-05:00";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString);

    System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
}
```

Output:

```
2020-02-11T17:26:31
```

Not that this uses a `DateTimeFormatter` without an offset for the output.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that your date string has an offset `-05:00` in it. Thus, your string does not represent a `LocalDateTime`, but an `OffsetDateTime`, and should be parsed by `OffsetDateTime.parse` (not everything is a `LocalDateTime`!):

```
// the format is ISO 8601, so it can be parsed directly without a DateTimeFormatter
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-02-11T17:26:31-05:00");
```

If you only want the local date time *part* of it, then you can call `toLocalDateTime` afterwards:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
```